# How do I get the status-text from a http.Response?

Tags: dart

How do I get the status-text from a http.Response?

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  final req = http.Request(method, Uri.parse('http://example.com'));
  final res = await http.Response.fromStream(await req.send());
  // HOW TO GET statusText???
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`res.statusCode` or `res.reasonPhrase`

Comment: yes, i was confused too. Better use Dio library, its easer and has. statusCode and statusMessage)